# How to put number in google sheet query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to do a query in google sheet something like:

```
=query({BY6:CH29},"
select Col2,sum(Col5*Col9*{144}/Col4),sum(Col5*Col10*{144}/Col4),sum(Col7*Col9*{144}/Col4),sum(Col7*Col10*{144}/Col4) 
where Col2 is not null
group by Col2 
order by Col1 
",1)
```

How do I do it? I think the number 144 made the formula error

the query return #VALUE!
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "*" "* "" at line 2, column 21. Was expecting: ")" ...

Comment: What is `144` here? Share a sample workbook and show your desired output.

Comment: 1 gross = 12 dozen

Comment: 1 dozen = 12 pieces, so 1 gross = 144 pcs, I try to convert the data to pieces, the data is a fraction to gross

Comment: = query({BY6:CH29}," select Col2,sum(Col5*Col9*{144}/Col4),sum(Col5*Col10*{144}/Col4),sum(Col7*Col9*{144}/Col4),sum(Col7*Col10*{144}/Col4) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 order by Col1 ",1)

all the asterisk is gone :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=query({BY6:CH29},"
select Col1, Col2,SUM(Col5)*SUM(Col9)*144/SUM(Col4),SUM(Col5)*SUM(Col10)*144/SUM(Col4),sum(Col7)*SUM(Col9)*144/SUM(Col4),sum(Col7)*SUM(Col10)*144/SUM(Col4) 
where Col2 is not null
group by Col2,Col1  
order by Col1 
",1)
```

Comment: I added Col1 to first selection and grouping, you may choose another aggregation option

Comment: thank you, so cannot put formula inside SUM() yes?

Comment: it works :thumbup:

Comment: You should use it column by column, yes. I'm glad it works!

Comment: By the way, welcome to StackOverflow, consider marking the question as answered. Good luck!